# Sorting a bag of biased coins with least flips - is it a well known problem?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, accuracy

I'm working on a practical problem which can be reduced to something like:

There is a bag of biased coins of two types with known biases (probability of heads are $p$ and $q$). The approximate ratio of coins is also known in advance.
The objective is to develop a strategy to sort coins with some level of confidence using as few coin tosses as possible.

The intuition: if $p=0.1$ and $q=0.6$, and we have three heads in a row, we have much higher confidence the coin being tossed is of type2 than if there was only one heads. In the former case, we might stop there, while in the latter we might need a few extra tosses to reach the desired level of confidence.

I'm not looking for help with the solution - it's doable with ~half a page of math. Instead, I'm looking for a shortcut to avoid explaining it - perhaps, by referring to a well known problem or a less known paper somebody probably wrote a hundred years ago.

I tried to search, but Google results are flooded with Bayes homework assignments. English is not my native language so perhaps even hinting the right keywords would be enough.

Comment: I suspect you might appreciate help with a solution, unless you're already familiar with the Sequential Probability Ratio Test and its mathematical basis.  You will want a Bayesian version to accommodate the prior information on the ratio.

Comment: @whuber thanks, that looks like a good read to start with. You're probably right, I wasn't aware of SPRT and might be missing important aspects of the problem

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the hint, sequential testing seems to be the topic I'm after. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?